# Why are existing but unused tags unusable?

Tags: bug, tags

*The annotation above is misleading. This question is about the **listing** of unused tags, leading the user to conclude that they are available. The bug is that they **behave** like new tags, but are also still **listed.***

So I've come upon a situation where there were more tags than one with no use associated with them. When I tried to use one of them, I got an error when I tried to submit my question:

> Creating the new tag '[tag name]' requires at least 500 reputation. Try something from the existing tags list instead.

Funny thing was, it was already listed. Is this a bug? Does it exist only on certain sites or across the network?

*Edit: I first encountered this issue several weeks ago, but apparently the tag I referenced has already been deleted.*

Comment: What site and tag?

Comment: I first encountered it with [puzzle] on Gaming. (Arquade)

Comment: Link to tag http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzles

Comment: @MartinSmith, as all sites use a similar engine, I elected to post here in case the bug exists in other sites as well, but I'll add the link.

Comment: Hmm... It appears that it is no longer in the main list.

Comment: Tags without posts are *zombie tags* and are cleared automatically once a day. They usually were created by accident, as typos. As such trying to add a zombie tag to a new post is equivalent to creating a new tag; you need to have a minimum reputation to do so. *This is by design*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So someone had used said tag and their question got deleted? Just to clarify, are zombie tags locked? In other words, are they unavailable to other users?

Comment: They are unavailable to people without the 500 minimum rep requirement for creating new tags. The tag could have been used on a question that has subsequently been removed or edited (where the edit removed the tag from the question).

Comment: Then the real bug is that they're still listed for those users, @Martijn.

Comment: It could have been caching; if the tag had become a zombie tag very recently it could have been available for autocompletion still. I think normally they are not included when zombied.

Comment: @Martijn I see many tags with no counts. Are they all zombies? How can we tell the difference?

Comment: What count are we talking about here? 0 followers or 0 questions tagged?

Comment: @Martijn I believe it's the missing `x[count]` next to the tag name in the main list, e.g. `tag-name x57`. I'm not clear on what that means, but in my experience, when the tag name appears by itself, with no count next to it, I generally can't use that tag.